# Creating reminders and alerts with Smartsheet API

Tags: smartsheet-api

I'm wondering how to create new reminders via the Java Smartsheet API. I haven't been able to find anything related to that. I thought it might be in the [Row](http://smartsheet-platform.github.io/smartsheet-java-sdk/com/smartsheet/api/models/Row.html) or [RowResources](http://smartsheet-platform.github.io/smartsheet-java-sdk/com/smartsheet/api/RowResources.html) class. Here is a quote from the launch of the API claiming that it can be done:

*"Use the API to automatically trigger events in Smartsheet. Automatically create project sheets or tasks, update and share
data, or send reminders."*

Has anyone successfully done this?

Answer (score 0):

The Smartsheet API does not currently support creating Alerts (i.e., reminders & notifications).  (Apologies for the confusion -- I've updated the blog post you quoted to remove the reference to Reminders.)

Comment: That's a shame :(. Any chance for future implementation?

Comment: Yes, definitely possible that this capability will be included in a future release of the Smartsheet API (although I'm unable to comment on specific time frame for that happening).  Thanks for letting us know that you're interested in this capability, as knowing which features matter most to our customers helps us better prioritize future enhancements to the API.

Comment: Is this something webhooks could be used for?